# Posearray bigger on rviz

Tags: gazebo, rviz, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I have a a list of poses that I use Posearray to publish to a topic. This works fine on rviz and I can see the arrows of each Pose. But I would like it to be easier to see, so making it bigger is needed. How can you make a Posearray arrow bigger?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/323549/posearray-bigger-on-rviz/) by [lidar_help](https://answers.ros.org/users/38728/lidar_help/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2019-05-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you expand the poseArray item in the left hand panel in RVIZ you will see options to control the size of the chosen marker type. Arrow length in the case of arrows, or more options in the case of 3D arrows or axes.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2019-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lidar_help](https://answers.ros.org/users/38728/lidar_help/) on 2019-05-22**:
The comment by Pete is correct:

"If you expand the poseArray item in the left hand panel in RVIZ you will see options to control the size of the chosen marker type. Arrow length in the case of arrows, or more options in the case of 3D arrows or axes."